# Create django project without generating comments

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to create a django project without all the *auto* generated comments in different files (such as reference links on `settings.py` and descriptions in `urls.py`)

I try to remove all those stuff after the project creation with some tools like [pyminifier](https://github.com/liftoff/pyminifier) and that works fine, but I find myself doing these tedious **comment removing** stuff every time I start a new project.

Is there any way that I can get prevent django from generating these data?

Something similar to this:

```
django-admin startproject <name> --no-comment
```

Comment: no there isn't. But you can just create your own starting template once and instead copy this into your project, just renaming the folder.

Comment: take a editor/IDE of your choice and run "find&replace" remove every line that starts with a "#". you probably need regex for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove the comments from settings or anywhere else from commandline.

But, in my humble opinion, the quickest or easiest way to fix this is to create a [cookie-cutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) variant of the Django which you want without any comments and use that for creating new django projects.

For doing it quicker, I would also recommend to look into [pydanny/django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) or any other [django cookie-cutter variants](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter#python-django) which suits your need most, fork them, remove the comments inside the project and push them in your git repository. Then you can simply use it like this:

```
pip install cookiecutter
cookiecutter  your-repo-git-url
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no such way in their documentation.
The second option is to create the files manually, I guess it will be more tedious